# Netgear VEGN2610 Router - wifi changing frequency

Tags: router, wireless-router, wifi-configuration

So I've pretty much looked everywhere (in Google and in my Router's config), still cannot explain it's behavior.

Every few minutes, every device that I own (two Lenovo laptops, one Asus laptop and one Android device) all disconnecting from the router.

Here's the related `dmesg` output:

```
[39361.363950] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: L1 Enabled - LTR Enabled
[39361.425341] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: L1 Enabled - LTR Enabled
[39361.425800] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: L1 Enabled - LTR Enabled
[39923.952833] wlp4s0: AP <Router MAC> changed bandwidth, new config is 2462 MHz, width 1 (2462/0 MHz)
[39923.952845] wlp4s0: AP <Router MAC> changed bandwidth in a way we can't support - disconnect
[39927.510701] wlp4s0: authenticate with <Router MAC>
[39927.518403] wlp4s0: send auth to <Router MAC> (try 1/3)
[39927.520303] wlp4s0: authenticated
[39927.520680] wlp4s0: associate with <Router MAC> (try 1/3)
[39927.524358] wlp4s0: RX AssocResp from <Router MAC> (capab=0x411 status=0 aid=2)
[39927.527738] wlp4s0: associated
```

(I've replaced my actual router's mac address with )
I also have got two devices connected by Ethernet cable, they are working just fine (no disconnections).

Before I'm going out to buy a new router -- is there any way to fix this?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Those client logs don't make any sense. There's no way for an AP to "change bandwidth to 0 MHz". Unless that's a stupid way of saying the client can see the AP's signal any more.

I wouldn't trust those logs. I would try to enable more verbose logging on the client and AP, plus maybe another client that doesn't use the same chipset and maybe isn't Linux-based. Then correlate the AP and multiple client debug logs to get a better picture.

Or better yet, get an 802.11 Monitor Mode packet capture of this event, preferably from an independent observer machine that is not associated to the network.

Do the log messages ever show a different 2.4GHz frequency, or does it always say 2462 (channel 11)?

Also, did you perform standard troubleshooting hygiene of making sure you have the latest firmware on your router and latest drivers and OS updates on your clients, in case your vendors already fixed this bug?

One last thing to try: If you're using WPA2/WPA mixed mode, where TKIP is still available, switch to WPA2-only mode, where only AES-CCMP is available.

Comment: Thanks for the reply :)

1) The log messages shows the same frequency every time, on two different computers.

2) Of course I've updated to the latest F/W.

3) Not using TKIP.

4) Logging on router says nothing regarding disconnections.

5) I have retried to connect to my 5Ghz network, seems to be working fine.

Comment: @amitizle Okay, time for a monitor mode packet trace from an unassociated computer.

Comment: LOL
I *think* I might've fixed it, somehow -- I've changed the preamble settings from 'Long' to 'Short'.